# Read CSV File with Spring Webflux and opencsv

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

Somebody knows how we can read CSV file using Spring Boot Web Flux and open Csv.

```
 @PostMapping
    fun uploadCsvFile(
        @RequestPart("file") filePart: FilePart
    ){
        

        filePart.content()
            .map { ??? }


    }
```

Comment: You don’t. OpenCSV is a blocking IO library. WebFlux is a reactive programming framework based on NIO. You can of course interoperable them, but most likely you’ll lose the benefit of using NIO on the web tier by using BIO on the file system tier.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. So do you have an idea how can I read the content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. may be can help someone

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    fun uploadCsvFile(@RequestPart("file") file: FilePart) = 
file.content().map {dataBuffer -> 
              dataBuffer.asInputStream().bufferedReader()
.use { createCSVToBean(it).parse() }
```

```
private fun createCSVToBean(fileReader: BufferedReader?): CsvToBean<**Your_DATA_CLASS**> =
    CsvToBeanBuilder<**Your_DATA_CLASS**>(fileReader)
        .withType(**Your_DATA_CLASS**::class.java)
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build()
```